# Referencing a cell in Excel using values from other cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to know if it is possible to reference a cell in Excel depending on the value of another cell.

Example

- I have a cell, let's say `A1` where I have the row number that I want to use (e.g., the content of `A1` is `42`)
- I want to compute the sum of column `B` from row `1` to the row corresponding to the number given in `A1`. Something like `=SUM( B1:B<NUMBER_IN_A1> )`

Is there any way?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `&` to create the cell coordinates, access them using `INDIRECT()`.

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("B1:B" & A1))
```

Comment: Not tagged for it, but this also works for OpenOffice Calc.

Answer (score 14):

`INDEX` is normally preferable to `INDIRECT`, where possible. You don't have to "hardcode" the column, and it's not (as) volatile.

```
=SUM(B1:INDEX(B:B,A1))
```

See the [documentation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/index-function-HP010342608.aspx) for more details on usage.

Comment: Thank you. INDEX is working with external references (without opening them), INDIRECT isn't.

Comment: Best to google "volatile functions" (incl. INDIRECT) for Excel and avoid these henceforth. (You may try and do sth fancy/elegant, but shoot yourself in the foot performance wise...)