# Reference cell range parameter from other cell dynamically in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I've got a simple range based formula

```
=SUM(A3:A$5)
```

I would like to dynamically assign the range value in the formula by referencing another cell's value, for example

cell B1 = 3 and cell B2 = 5

```
=SUM(A<referenced value from B1>:A$<referenced value from B2>)
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use the `INDIRECT` function

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("A"&B1&":A"&B2))
```

Note: I haven't tested this formula, let me know if there are any problems

Comment: `=SUM(INDIRECT("A"&B1&":A"&C1))` yep

Comment: I don't see **C1** referenced?

Comment: It's what I used

Answer (score 2):

Using `INDEX` works too.

```
=SUM(INDEX(A:A,B1):INDEX(A:A,B2))
```

Referencing [an earlier answer](https://superuser.com/a/386703/380641) which suggests using this method instead of `INDIRECT`.

Comment: Maybe, I did something wrong with your solution. That didn't help me.
I did look for an existing answer, but somehow I've overlooked the earlier answer you have referenced. Thanks